# check if value greater than a number exists in 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2d array in the format

```
emi_309 | weak   | 16
emi_310 | strong | 9
emi_319 | medium | 8
emi_315 | weak   | 5
```

I want to check if a value greater that a certain number (e.g > 5) exists in the 3rd column using a simple function like the following:

```
  ($.inArray( conditions greater than 5 here, $.map(myArray, function(v) { return v[2]; })) > -1)
```

How do I include the condition (>5) in the above function?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: JavaScript has jagged arrays not multidimensional arrays

Comment: What is your actual data structure?

Comment: jQuery's inArray only checks if a particular value is included.  It does not check an arbitrary condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to use [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) in this case:

```
if ($.grep(myArray, function(v) { return v[2] > 5; }).length) {
    // values > 5 exist
}
```

Comment: @ScottSauyet `$.inArray` solution will be **very** ugly for the current example.

Comment: I mentioned in comments to the original that .inArray would not work.  I'm suggesting also that .grep is not particularly performant.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Why not? Here is stupid example with `$.inArray`: `$.inArray(5, $.map(myArray, function(v) { return Math.min(v[2], 5); }));`. However `$.map` also won't gain the performance. The fastest way is to use `for` loop, besides it won't be short.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.inArray` only tests against a specific value (checks equality) so it will not help you in this case.

you could change the inArray to be able to handle a predicate as it's first argument.
Changing "base libraries" like this should be done carefully and you might want to create a different function. However in this specific case I feel that the ability to pass a function resembles that of other jQuery functions

```
var org_inArray = $.inArray
$.inArray = function(value, array, fromIndex){
  if($.isFunction(value)){

      var start = fromIndex || 0,
          matches = $.grep(myArray.slice(start), function(e,i) { 
         if(value(e,i)) return i;
      }
      return matches ? matches[0] : -1; 
  } else {
     arguments.length > 2 ? 
             org_inArray.call($,value,array,fromIndex) :
             org_inArray.call($,value,array)
  }
}
```

you would then be able to use it like

```
if($.inArray( function(e) { return e[2] > 5;}, myArray) !== -1){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is pretty simple:

```
var firstMatch = function(arr, cond) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (cond(arr[i])) {return i;}
    } 
    return -1;
};

if (firstMatch(myArray, function(v) { return v[2] > 5; }) > -1) { ... }
```

If you really want this in the jQuery namespace, just attach it to jQuery:

```
jQuery.firstMatch = function(Arr, cond) { ...
```

and call it like

```
if ($.firstMatch(myArray, function(v) { return v[2] > 5; }) > -1) { ... }
```